# AS3 why Sound effect doesn't work on Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, adobe, adobe-animate

I've built a fairly simple app using Adobe Animate and AS3, which has a number of buttons that should play a sound when tapping on them. when running a Test of the app the sounds works just fine. but when testing/debugging the app on an Android emulator or an Android device the sound doesn't work.

The sound file called "click.mp3" is loaded to Animate's library. It has a class file called "Click"[screenshot of the sound setting in Animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ThxE.jpg)

Here is a sample of my code.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; //importing touch mode
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite; //importing sprite mode
import flash.text.TextFormat;

var mysound: Click = new Click(); // Sound mode

var sumButton: int; // Variable for Master Sum button 
var digiButton: int; // Variable for Master Digi Button
var masterArray: Array = new Array(); //Master array veriable
sumButton = 0;
digiButton = 0;

// Text Format for the sum buttons --------------------------------------------------------------------------
var newFormat: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
newFormat.size = 52;
newFormat.font = "Arial";
newFormat.align = "center";

//Sum Button 2 ------------------------------------------------
var square2: Sprite = new Sprite();
square2.graphics.beginFill(0x666666);
square2.graphics.drawRect(20, 190, 65, 65);
square2.graphics.endFill();
square2.buttonMode = true;
square2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, myTap2);

var myTF2: TextField = new TextField();
myTF2.x = 20;
myTF2.y = 190;
myTF2.width = 65;
myTF2.height = 65;
myTF2.border = true;
myTF2.borderColor = 0x10AD63;
myTF2.textColor = 0xFFFF99;
myTF2.wordWrap = false;
myTF2.appendText("2");
myTF2.setTextFormat(newFormat);

square2.addChild(myTF2);
this.addChild(square2);

function myTap2(event: TouchEvent): void {
    sumButton = 2;
    mysound.play();

}
```

Here is how the class "click" code looks like:

```
package  {
    
    import flash.media.Sound;
    
    
    public class Click extends Sound {
        
        
        public function Click() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }
    
}
```

Why does the sound not playing on Android?

Comment: Check if the handler is actually invoked on tap. If it is not, try **MouseEvent.CLICK** rather than tap event.

Comment: Would android recognize mouse even as a tap?

Comment: Check this one: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#mapTouchToMouse

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to Check on the "Override Sound Setting" settings on the Publish Settings.

[image: Sound setting on the Publish Settings]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using *"**Override sound settings**"*, declare your MP3 variable as a `Sound` data type.

```
//# correct... play works as expected
var mysound: Sound = new Click();

//# wrong... play needs override to work 
var mysound: Click = new Click();
```

Comment: ok great, but curious, what is wrong with overriding sound settings?

Comment: Your `mysound` audio is of type `Sound` data so keep it like that if you want to use sound without problems later (for now you are lucky it works)... If you want `mysound` to be of `Click` data type then go ahead and override its `Sound` setting because maybe you have code or functions in the `Click` class that you wanted?. Keep audio as `new Sound` and code as `new Class`.

Comment: I made the `var mysound: Sound = new Click();` changes but it didn't work on my android I still needed to override the sound settings.

Comment: That al isl **extremely** weird because AFAIK that '*Override Sound Settings*' only affects the way the audio tracks are exported into the resulting SWF. If it is on, Flash packs all sounds as **MP3**s of appointed quality with no regard to distinct tracks' own settings. I have just one wild idea about the cause of the problem: the original sound tracks are in some weird rare format/codec that is supported by Flash Player / PC but not supported by Android.